# Justified captions with KOMA-Script and ragged2e

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script, ragged2e

I just stumbled across some phenomena.  I am using KOMA-Script book `scrbook` and have loaded the package `ragged2e`.  Usually, I do load that package with the option `newcommands`, to be able to use commands as `\raggedright` and have hyphenation.

The actual document has some floating images, which incorporate the `\caption`-command as well.  Some have even the `besidescaption`-environment of the KOMA-Script classes.

In one case, I stumbled upon two floats on one page.  One using the normal `\caption`, one using the `besidescaption`-environment.  In the latter, the caption text was justified, but in the former float, the caption text was flush left and ragged right margin.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}

%% This works as expected
% \usepackage{ragged2e}
%% This gives strange results
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\chapter{We need justification}
\label{cha:justification}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption[short caption]{Some random text, just ordinary text, which
    should be some words and lines long.  This text should be
    presented in justified form, as is all the rest of the text of
    this book.  Be careful.  Have a closer look.  This text is flush
    left instead of justified.  What on earth is going on?}
  \label{fig:flushleft}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{captionbeside}
    [Another short story]{This is a smaller image, where the caption
      is not given below, but beside the image.  Thanks to Markus
      Kohm, who did a great job with this often requested feature.
      This caption text is presented in justified form, as you would
      and should expect.}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{captionbeside}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here are the results.  First is the display, of unexpected version:

[image: incorrect result]

It should instead look like this:

[image]

I think this is a bug?

Comment: Don't know if it's a bug, but the `ragged2e` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ragged2e/ragged2e.pdf), [p. 6](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ragged2e/ragged2e.pdf#page.6), explains that the option `newcommands` subtitutes `\centering` with `\Centering`; if you do this manually without the option enabled, the very same output is produced.

Comment: This is not a KOMA-Script bug. Using a standard class you will get the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\setcaptionalignment{J}` after loading package `ragged2e`. Alignment `J` means fully justified with `ragged2e` (see the KOMA-Script documentation).

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\setcaptionalignment{J}% <- added
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{We need justification}
\label{cha:justification}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption[short caption]{Some random text, just ordinary text, which
    should be some words and lines long.  This text should be
    presented in justified form, as is all the rest of the text of
    this book.  Be careful.  Have a closer look.  This text is flush
    left instead of justified.  What on earth is going on?}
  \label{fig:flushleft}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{captionbeside}
    [Another short story]{This is a smaller image, where the caption
      is not given below, but beside the image.  Thanks to Markus
      Kohm, who did a great job with this often requested feature.
      This caption text is presented in justified form, as you would
      and should expect.}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also replace `\centering` by `\LaTeXcentering`:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{We need justification}
\label{cha:justification}
\begin{figure}
  \LaTeXcentering% <- changed
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption[short caption]{Some random text, just ordinary text, which
    should be some words and lines long.  This text should be
    presented in justified form, as is all the rest of the text of
    this book.  Be careful.  Have a closer look.  This text is flush
    left instead of justified.  What on earth is going on?}
  \label{fig:flushleft}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{captionbeside}
    [Another short story]{This is a smaller image, where the caption
      is not given below, but beside the image.  Thanks to Markus
      Kohm, who did a great job with this often requested feature.
      This caption text is presented in justified form, as you would
      and should expect.}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Using `\LaTeXcentering` will also work with a standard class:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{book}% standard class
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{We need justification}
\label{cha:justification}
\begin{figure}
  \LaTeXcentering% <- changed
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption[short caption]{Some random text, just ordinary text, which
    should be some words and lines long.  This text should be
    presented in justified form, as is all the rest of the text of
    this book.  Be careful.  Have a closer look.  This text is flush
    left instead of justified.  What on earth is going on?}
  \label{fig:flushleft}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay yeah this is much better than my answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

The [`ragged2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) [manual, page 6](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ragged2e/ragged2e.pdf#page.6), explains that the option `newcommands` subtitutes `\centering` with `\Centering`; if you do this manually without the option enabled (i.e. use `\Centering` instead of `\centering` without loading `newcommands`), the very same output is produced.

One quick fix would be to simply save the old `\centering` before loading `\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}` and then using that instead of `\centering` in the `figure` environment:

```
\let\oldcentering\centering
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
```

---

**Edit**: This is actually precisely what `\LaTeXcentering` (see [@esdd's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540248/170958)) is, see [§7.10 of the `ragged2e` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ragged2e/ragged2e.pdf#subsection.7.10) (excerpt below).

[image: screenshot]

---

Or, alternatively, as described on [page 3 of the `ragged2e` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ragged2e/ragged2e.pdf#page.3), you may use `\justifying` inside of the caption environment to turn justification back on, as in `\caption{\justifying Lorem ipsum}`.

Both of the fixes should also prevent the `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` warnings that you'd get otherwise (or at least I did).

---

**Edit**: For a less tedious solution, using KOMA-Script, see [@esdd's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540248/170958). Alternatively, and this should work for both KOMA-Script and regular classes, you can use the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package:

```
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

% see page 25 of the `caption` manual:
% http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\justifying}
\captionsetup{justification=justified}
```

MWE for [`scrbook`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrbook) class:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\justifying}
\captionsetup{justification=justified}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{Some random text, just ordinary text, which should
    be some words and lines long.  This text should be
    presented in justified form, as is all the rest of the text of
    this book.  Be careful.  Have a closer look.  This text is flush
    left instead of justified.  What on earth is going on?}
  \label{fig:flushleft}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

That the scope of the `\Centering` command also includes the content of the `\caption` command, well, that might be a bug. I don't know.

PS: "We need justification" is hilarious, I love it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am glad you noticed it and even love it :-)